# c++11 Isomorphic Class Adapters For yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

So in the [yaml-cpp](https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp) provides a main interface for converting user-made types into `YAML::Node` - namely:

```
template<typename T>
struct convert
{
   <static member functions to define interface>
}
```

So here's the idea. Let's say we have a type `SomeOtherType` that's assumed to have a template specialization for the above interface (it's isomorphic to `YAML::Node`. And then I write a custom type `MyType` that is isomorphic to `std::vector<SomeOtherType>` - which I implement through some interface struct that is similar in principle to the above struct (for example a struct as follows: `template<typename T> struct ToStdVec {...}`). Here's a graphic to help explain my thinking:

```
MyType <----> std::vector<SomeOtherType> <----> YAML::Node
  |--- trivial ---|                 |--- trivial ---|
```

Because the above two conversions are trivial it seems that there should be some way to get the compiler to automagically generate the template specialization for `convert<MyType>` as above - of course given the correct structure. Indeed this seems plausible for a given set of isomorphims:

```
MyType <---> SomeContainer
SomeContainer <---> AnotherType
MyType <---> AnotherType     <--- can the compiler generate this given the above two isomorphisms?
```

My current approach (which isn't clean IMHO) is as follows:

1. Implement the trivial interface `template<typename T> convert<ToStdVec<T>>`
2. Implement the trivial interface `template<> ToStdVec<MyType>`
3. Write a macro that generates the `template<> convert<MyType> { <use ToStdVec to convert> }`

Essentially I want to know if it's possible to use template meta-programming or some other C++11 feature to have the compiler automagically generate step 3.

Essentially it's similar to the following Haskell code:

```
data Node = Node

class YAMLConvert a where
  encode :: a -> Node
  decode :: Node -> a

-- | a trivial implementation provided for exmaple
instance YAMLConvert [a] where
  encode _ = Node
  decode _ = []

-- | the StdVec conversion interface where Int is our base type
class StdVec a where
  to :: a -> [Int]
  from :: [Int] -> a

-- | This won't compile however it's provided to show the concept
instance (StdVec a) => YAMLConvert a where
  encode = encode . to
  decode = from . decode
```

NOTE: this question not the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608273/defining-custom-input-types-for-the-new-yaml-cpp-api) one.